# Unable to save tab of custom app in teams scope

Tags: microsoft-teams

[image]

I can open my app independently in my own panel but cant add it to a team  im owner of. Is there a rule against this or am I missing somthing ?

Please ask for any infomation im missing, new to teams development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Needed to add 'team' scope for static tabs in the manifest.json