# Unable to add custom Teams Tab built using AppStudio

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to add a webpage to the teams tab, using the step provided here.
https://microsoft.github.io/BotFramework-WebChat/19.c.single-sign-on-for-teams-apps/

Only thing is, I am not building a personal tab, but instead a teams tab

I have tried this solution, but I get error on parsing of manifest file.
And I am not sure what the "entityId" in the below solution should be

[Unable to save tab of custom app in teams scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616328/unable-to-save-tab-of-custom-app-in-teams-scope)

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.5",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "id": "fd0e40dd-3c92-4db1-b777-ed37c1a912df",
    "packageName": "https://www.google.com",
    "developer": {
        "name": "My Company",
        "websiteUrl": "https://www.google.com",
        "privacyUrl": "https://www.google.com/privacy.html",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.google.com/termsofuse.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "Web chat sso",
        "full": ""
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "ompany landing page with ",
        "full": "Web Chat and Single Sign-On"
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "configurableTabs": [
        {
            "configurationUrl": "https://webchat-sample-sso.azurewebsites.net",
            "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
            "scopes": [
                "team",
                "groupchat"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "webchat-sample-sso.azurewebsites.net",
        "www.azurewebsites.net",
        "google.com"
    ],
    "staticTabs":[
      {
        "name": "Webchatsso",
        "contentUrl":"https://webchat-sample-sso.azurewebsites.net",
        "scopes":[
                  "team"]
      }]
}
```

I am expecting the prompt to save successfully, to see the webpage on the tab where any team member can view at, but this doesnt happen as the "Save" button is disabled, same as the screenshot below.[image]

Comment: Could you please confirm if you have set microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true); in your [configuration page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/configuration-page)

Comment: Thank you very much! that worked. I dint know the point about using a ConifgurationPage and ContentPage. That link helped me to understand it further.